# Install4J: DMG -> is it possible to eject the DMG after the install?

Tags: install4j, dmg

I'm using Install4J 9.0.7 to create installers for my java application that run on Linux, OS/x and Windows.  I also am doing automatic updates of the code each time the app is launched.  After the update, I have it re-launch the application.

The only annoying thing is that after the "install" the DMG directory is still mounted and must be manually "ejected" by the user.  Is there an easy way to have the DMG eject at the end of the install?

Searched the online documentation and crawled through the installer options and additional actions but couldn't find this action.

Answer (score 1):

As of install4j 10, this is not supported. Generally, this is not easily solved because the installer is running from the mounted DMG and it cannot unmount its own executable path.